# Let $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\mu<\infty$ for all $i>0$ and $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. Is $\mathbb{E}(|X_{n}S_n+n\mu^2-\mu S_n-n\mu X_n|)$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, expected-value

The $X_i$'s are independent.

It is my intention to show that this is (hopefully) bounded to aid with a reuslt, however to me it doesn't look to be the case. I applied a triangle inequality to get that the above expectation is bounded by:

$$\mathbb{E}|Y_nS_n| + n|\mu^2|+\mathbb{E}|\mu S_n| + n\mathbb{E}|\mu Y_n|$$

But the 1st, 3rd, 4th terms don't look bounded to me due to dependence on $n$. Am I missing something or is the expectation simply not bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d taking values $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac  1 2$ each. Then the question is one about boundedness of $(E|S_n|)$. There are many ways of showing that this is not true.